# IPad Safari <audio> not playing

Tags: ipad, html, audio, safari

I want to play an mp3 on iPad Safari..
Here is my code

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
        audio.src = audioUrl;
        x.appendChild(audio);
        audio.play();
```

For some reasons, i get an error ..movie cannot be played, even though it is mp3..

Though works fine on Windows Safari..

I have tried 2 things;

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.type = "audio/mpeg";
    audio.src = audioUrl;         
    x.appendChild(audio);
    audio.play();
```

and

```
x.innerHTML = '<audio autoplay=autoplay><source src="'+audioUrl + '" type=audio/mpeg /></audio>';
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add:

```
audio.type='audio/mpeg';
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your reply..So this is needed for iPad Safari only and not for desktop Safari..

Comment: It's actually always needed, it's just implied by most browsers (though apparently not by iPad's Safari).

Comment: So this is by JS..I guess there must be an equivalent attribute if we set it as HTML tag directly..

Comment: It's not js-specific, and the attribute is `type='audio/mpeg'`.

Comment: I tried that..Still get the same error...movie cannot be played ...added audio.type='audio/mpeg';

Comment: I tried in 2 ways...as edited/updated in my original question.. Both do not work on the iPad Safari..works on desktop..